# Renaming a collection in solr cloud 4.4 set up

Tags: collections, solr

I have solr cloud 4.4 set up with two shard and 0 replicas. How can I rename the collection after it is created.

Answer (score 3):

These are from my academic understanding, first try on a test installation before you do these in much serious environments:

One options is to rename solr directoy name and auto discovery (core.properties) name as

```
name=collection1
```

For example rename collection1 to mycollection and edit core.properties as

```
name=mycollection
```

and restart your server.

Another option is to use collection aliasing:

```
http://host:port/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=newname&collections=oldnme
```

This is meant for advance use but you can try this.